# Dom contains or compareDocumentPosition analog in react

Tags: reactjs

I have some component that contains another portaled component like

```
<Parent>
    <Portal>
        <Child>Lorem Ipsum</Child>
    </Portal>
</Parent>
```

But on real dom it look's like:

```
<div class="parent"></div>
<div class="child">Lorem Ipsum</div>
```

I need to know, that native node of Child component is child of Parent.

Comment: @Chris thanks for edit. It's my first question on stackoverflow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i had a slightly different problem. And that the Parent containes Child, we can know from event bubbling.

Portal:

```
class Portal extends React.Component {
  el: any;

  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props);
    this.el = document.createElement('div');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    document.body.appendChild(this.el);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    document.body.removeChild(this.el);
  }

  render() {
    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
      this.props.children,
      this.el,
    );
  }
}
```

Child:

```
class Child extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="child">Lorem Ipsum</div>;
  }
}
```

Parent:

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  target: any;

  componentDidMount () {
    document.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onDocMouseDown);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    document.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onDocMouseDown);
  }

  onDocMouseDown = (e: any) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const isChild = this.target === target;

    if (isChild) {
      // do something
    }

    this.target = null;

  };

  onElemMouseDown = (e: any) => {
    this.target = e.target;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="parent" onMouseDown={this.onElemMouseDown}>
        <Portal>
          <Child />
        </Portal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

From React Portal documentation:

> An event fired from inside a portal will propagate to ancestors in the
>   containing React tree, even if those elements are not ancestors in the
>   DOM tree

In Parent class we have handle for event 'mousedown' on document and on the wrapper div. When mousedown is fired, first will work wrapper handle. We save it to some variable like 'this.target'. Then event bubbling to document and in handle for document we can equal 'e.target' with 'this.target'. Accordingly we can to know is this target in Parent or not.